# Writing a code to give back the least amount of coins for a user inputted number. I have no clue why the results aren't printing

Tags: java

I am not sure how to get the proper results to print out, and am not sure why it isn't giving the correct response when it is. The beginning code was starter code I was told not to touch.

I tried moving the location of the print statement, but it would end up printing one quarter and nothing else.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int quarters = 0;
    int dimes = 0;
    int nickels = 0;
    int pennies = 0;
        //prompt the user for a monetary input
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        double changeToGive = 0;
        
        do {
            //if the user gave us a negative dollar amount
            if(changeToGive < 0)
                System.out.println("Dollar amounts must be positive.");
            
            //if the current amount is zero dollars
            else if(changeToGive == 0)
                System.out.println("How much change do you need to pay out?");
            
            // while the user's input is not a valid double, prompt again
            while (!sc.hasNextDouble()) {
                System.out.println("Invalid input.  How much change do you need to pay out?");
                sc.next(); // this is important!
            }
            
            //if the user entered a valid double, assign it to changeToGive
            changeToGive = sc.nextDouble();
        } while (changeToGive <= 0); //if the user entered a valid double but it was negative, do it all again

     while (changeToGive > 0){ 
    if (changeToGive >= .25){
    changeToGive -= .25;
    quarters++;
    }else if (changeToGive >= .10){
    changeToGive -= .10;
    dimes++;
    }else if (changeToGive >= .5){
    changeToGive -= .5;
    nickels++;
    }else if (changeToGive >= .1){
    changeToGive -= .1;
    pennies++;
    }
     }
    System.out.print("Your change is:\n"+quarters+" quarters\n"+dimes+" dimes\n"+nickels+" nickels\n"+pennies+" pennies\n");
       
    
    
    

    }
    
      
    }
```

Comment: If was your tutor you just failed because you used a floating point type for money. Hopefully your tutor isn't an utter utter b&*%$d like me :-) It is possible that the double is the cause of your problem. changeToGive could be getting very close to 0 (but still > 0 but less than .1 so it never changes).

Comment: The trick is to use `int` (not `double`!) for *everything*, including the price, by storing amounts as the integer quantity of *cents*.

Answer (score 1):

After making `changeToGive` an `int` instead of a `double` (plus removal of a small amount of unnecessary code), you'll have a working solution:

```
int quarters = 0;
int dimes = 0;
int nickels = 0;
int pennies = 0;
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int changeToGive = 0;

do {
    // if the user gave us a negative dollar amount
    if (changeToGive < 0)
        System.out.println("Dollar amounts must be positive.");

    // prompt the user for a monetary input
    System.out.println("How much change do you need to pay out?");

    // while the user's input is not a valid double, prompt again
    while (!sc.hasNextDouble()) {
        System.out.println("Invalid input. How much change do you need to pay out?");
        sc.next(); // this is important!
    }

    // if the user entered a valid double, assign it to changeToGive
    changeToGive = (int) (sc.nextDouble() * 100); // cents
} while (changeToGive <= 0); //if the user entered a valid double but it was negative, do it all again

while (changeToGive > 0) {
    if (changeToGive >= 25) {
        changeToGive -= 25;
        quarters++;
    } else if (changeToGive >= 10) {
        changeToGive -= 10;
        dimes++;
    } else if (changeToGive >= 5) {
        changeToGive -= 5;
        nickels++;
    } else {
        changeToGive -= 1;
        pennies++;
    }
}

System.out.print("Your change is:\n" + quarters + " quarters\n" + dimes + " dimes\n" + nickels + " nickels\n" + pennies + " pennies\n");
```

---

For bonus marks, use an `enum` of coins, each with a `value` field, rather than hard coding them. Left to you to investigate.

Answer (score 0):

> *"... I am not sure how to get the proper results to print out, and am not sure why it isn't giving the correct response when it is. ..."*

You've incorrectly denoted a *5 cent* and *1 cent* value as *0.5* and *0.1*, instead of *0.05*, and *0.01*.

```java
if (changeToGive >= .5) changeToGive -= .5;
if (changeToGive >= .1) changeToGive -= .1;
```

Additionally, the *changeToGive* value is mutating as you deduct the values.

Here is an iteration for *0.99*.

```
0.99 - .25 = 0.74
0.74 - .25 = 0.49
0.49 - .25 = 0.24
0.24 - .10 = 0.13999999999999999
0.13999999999999999 - .10 = 0.03999999999999998
0.03999999999999998 - 0.01 = 0.029999999999999978
0.029999999999999978 - 0.01 = 0.019999999999999976
0.019999999999999976 - 0.01 = 0.009999999999999976
```

As suggested by *Java*, use the *[BigDecimal](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html)* class for *currency* application.

*[Primitive Data Types (The Java™ Tutorials > Learning the Java Language > Language Basics)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)*.

> *The float data type ... This data type should never be used for precise values, such as currency. For that, you will need to use the [[java.math.BigDecimal]](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html) class instead.*

Here is an example.

```java
import static java.math.BigDecimal.ZERO;
import static java.math.RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
```

```java
int quarters = 0;
int dimes = 0;
int nickels = 0;
int pennies = 0;
//prompt the user for a monetary input
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
BigDecimal changeToGive = ZERO.setScale(2, HALF_EVEN), z = ZERO,
           q = new BigDecimal(".25"), d = new BigDecimal(".10"),
           n = new BigDecimal(".05"), p = new BigDecimal(".01");

do {
    //if the user gave us a negative dollar amount
    if(changeToGive.compareTo(z) < 0)
        System.out.println("Dollar amounts must be positive.");

        //if the current amount is zero dollars
    else if(changeToGive.compareTo(z) == 0)
        System.out.println("How much change do you need to pay out?");

    // while the user's input is not a valid double, prompt again
    while (!sc.hasNextBigDecimal()) {
        System.out.println("Invalid input.  How much change do you need to pay out?");
        sc.next(); // this is important!
    }

    //if the user entered a valid double, assign it to changeToGive
    changeToGive = sc.nextBigDecimal();
} while (changeToGive.compareTo(z) <= 0); //if the user entered a valid double but it was negative, do it all again

while (changeToGive.compareTo(z) > 0){
    if (changeToGive.compareTo(q) >= 0){
        changeToGive = changeToGive.subtract(q);
        quarters++;
    }else if (changeToGive.compareTo(d) >= 0){
        changeToGive = changeToGive.subtract(d);
        dimes++;
    }else if (changeToGive.compareTo(n) >= 0){
        changeToGive = changeToGive.subtract(n);
        nickels++;
    }else if (changeToGive.compareTo(p) >= 0){
        changeToGive = changeToGive.subtract(p);
        pennies++;
    }
}
System.out.print("Your change is:\n"+quarters+" quarters\n"+dimes+" dimes\n"+nickels+" nickels\n"+pennies+" pennies\n");
```

Output

```
How much change do you need to pay out?
.99
Your change is:
3 quarters
2 dimes
0 nickels
4 pennies
```